# MYSQL self-join to select last year sales

Tags: mysql, self-join

I'm trying to select historical totals (t1.date - 1 for now) off of a range of given dates (t1.DATE >= '2011-01-01' AND t1.DATE <= '2011-11-11')

```
SELECT 
t1.date as DATE, SUM(t1.total), t2.date, sum(t2.total)
FROM T_SALES t1

LEFT OUTER JOIN T_SALES t2
on (t2.date = (t1.date - 1)
AND t2.rc = t1.rc
AND t2.storenum = t1.storenum)
WHERE 
    t1.RC = 0 
AND t1.STORENUM = '1,'
AND t1.DATE >= '2011-01-01' 
AND t1.DATE <= '2011-11-11' 
GROUP BY t1.date

ORDER BY t1.DATE ASC
```

My 2nd aggregate t2.total is where my problem is - SUM(t1.total) represents accurate sales totals)

Below is my output

[image]

The value 27.90, should be 5.58--It looks like I'm over summing on sum(t2.total).

Grouping by t1.total shows that as well: (5.58 * 5 = 27.90)

[image]

I've tried every imaginable grouping but just can't get it right, any ideas out there?  thanks all!

Comment: You are trying to get historical totals based on a range of dates? I don't understand why you are joining the table to itself to do this? I think you need to provide more detail on what you are trying to achieve, or my hunch is that you are trying to do too much in one query. I can't easily see why you would want to join the table to itself with t1.Date = t2.Date - 1. What is the rc field? Probably you want to use nested select queries, and then join these together on the date.

Comment: It's pretty clear (well, to me) that the OP is trying to compare day-to-day sales, a pretty common metric in retail.

Comment: I think gregory is raising a good point. joining a table by itself is a bit confusing, but instead if you want to compare dates you could still do this on the where clause by the use of subquery in that way you'll never gonna need to use join statements anymore.

Comment: Self joins are pretty common in SQL applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're getting a semi-cartesian product between the two tables — two sales in the T1 table and three sales in the T2 table will produce six rows in the pre-aggregated result set.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Aggregate the tables *first* and then JOIN the aggregated tables together.
2. Base the entire query off a simple select on the first table and nest a query in the results to get the second total.

Here's solution 1 (note that this is broken down by RC (region code?) and storenum, if that's not what you want simple remove all references to those columns):

```
CREATE VIEW DailyTotals (RC, StoreNum, Date, TotalAmount) AS 
SELECT RC, StoreNum, Date, SUM(Total) FROM T_Sales
GROUP BY RC, StoreNum, Date

SELECT TODAY.RC, TODAY.StoreNum, TODAY.Date, TODAY.TotalAmount, 
       YDAY.Date, YDAY.TotalAmount
FROM DailyTotals TODAY 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN DailyTotals YDAY ON YDAY.Date = TODAY.Date-1
WHERE TODAY.Date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-11-11'
```

and here's solution 2 (again with region and store breakdown, which can be removed):

```
  SELECT RC, StoreNum, Date, SUM(Total), Date-1,
    (SELECT SUM(Total) FROM T_Sales YDAY WHERE 
     YDAY.RC = TODAY.RC AND YDAY.StoreNum = TODAY.StoreNum AND YDAY.Date = TODAY.Date-1)
  FROM T_Sales TODAY WHERE Date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-11-11'
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe sub-selects?

```
select *
  from (
select sum(total)
     , date 
     , rc
     , storenum
 from T_SALES
group by date, rc, storenum)T1
left join(
select sum(total)
     , date 
     , rc
     , storenum
 from T_SALES
group by date, rc, storenum)T2
 on T2.date = (T1.date - 1)
and T2.storenum = T1.storenum
```

Answer (score 0):

try to modify your query into something like this:

```
SELECT 
t1.date as DATE, SUM(t1.total), t1.date, sum(t1.total)
FROM T_SALES t1
WHERE 
    t1.RC = 0 
AND t1.STORENUM = '1,'
t1.date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-11-11' 
GROUP BY t1.date
ORDER BY t1.date ASC
```

your aliases t1 and t2 are just using the same table and do the computation you need again. your previous query is very confusing. then add the conditions you need on the where statement and post how you did it again here